# Problema con la validación de enteros en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, validación, dev-c++, visual-studio-2017

Después de haber estudiado algunas funciones de la librería `cctype` como `isdigit` e `isalpha` decidí crear un programa, inspirado en unos tutoriales que vi en yt, para validar números enteros.

A continuación mi código:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool tipo_i_valido(string s);
int capturar_i();

int main()
{
    int numero;

    numero = capturar_i();
    cout << "El numero ingresado es: " << numero << "\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool tipo_i_valido(string s)
{
    int i, longitud_s;

    longitud_s = s.length();

    if (longitud_s == 1)
    {
        if (!isdigit(s[0]))     
            return 0;       
    }
    else
    {
        if (s[0] == '+' || s[0] == '-' || isdigit(s[0]) != 0)
        {
            for (i = 1; i < longitud_s; i++)
            {
                if (!isdigit(s[i]))             
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        else
            return 0;       
    }
    return 1;
}

int capturar_i()
{
    int n_numero;
    string numero;
    bool es_valido;

    do {
        cout << "Ingrese un numero:\t";
        getline(cin, numero);
        cout << "\n";

        es_valido = tipo_i_valido(numero);

        if (!es_valido)
            cout << "ERROR. Ingrese solo numeros enteros.\n" << endl;
    } while (!es_valido);

    n_numero = stoi(numero);

    return n_numero;
}
```

Como ven lo que hago es ingresar una cadena y si resulta ser un número entero incluido el signo como, por ejemplo, `+24` o `-12`, entonces lo considera válido y el programa hace la conversión de la cadena por medio de `stoi`. Mi problema radica en que por alguna razón en el VS 2017, al ejecutar mi programa, si pongo el carácter `ñ` el programa se "crashea" y me sale el siguiente mensaje: "debug assertion failed [...]". Sin embargo, el código anterior, después de compilarlo en Dev C++ 5.11, al ejecutarlo funciona con total normalidad.

¿A qué se debe que en el VS el caracter `ñ` crashea mi programa, pero en el Dev C++ no?

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas y/o comentarios

Comment: Revisa que tipo de codificacion utiliza visual studio para los strings.

Comment: @eyllanesc en qué parte del visual studio se puede revisar eso?

Comment: Te recomiendo validar si el caracter es alfanumerico con `isalpha()` asi te evitas el problema con `ñ` y las tildes.

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir "crashea"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se debe al funcionamiento de las funciones `isXXX`, entre ellas `isdigit( )`, en combinación con la codificación de caracteres de tu sistema.

Según el [estándar](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1):

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is *undefined*.

En traducción *libre* por mi parte:

> En todos los casos, el argumento es un `int`, cuyo valor ha de ser representable en un `unsigned char` o `EOF`.
>   Si el argumento tiene cualquier otro valor, el comportamiento es *indefinido*.

Ahí tienes el motivo. Tu sistema codifica el caracter `'ñ'` como un valor numérico **no representable en un `unsigned char`** (seguramente utilice `wchar_t` para los caracteres).

En estos casos, el compilador es libre de *salvar la situación como buenamente pueda*; VS2017 te muestra el mensaje, mientras que el compilador incluido en Dev C++ 5.11 seguro que utiliza otro tipo para los caracteres, y es capaz de *lidiar* con caracteres no-ASCII.

En cualquier caso, **ambos compiladores** están en lo correcto. Es lo que tienen los *comportamientos indefinidos* ;-)